# Client crashing when running command with Renci SshNet

Tags: c#, ssh

Currently, when I press the button, it is supposed to restart one of our servers and upon completion return the result. The command runs successfully but after running it, the client crashes because technically the command never really finishes.

After running the command, the server starts running and it will keep outputting server information in the console about the server. How would i make it so that it stops by default after like 15 seconds, or when the output stream is returning emptiness.

I am new to C# so not sure how to approach this.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new SshClient("IP", "USER", "PASS"))
        {

            label1.Text = "Status: Initiated restart";
            client.Connect();
            var cmd = client.RunCommand("./server restart && ./server2 restart");
            var result = cmd.Execute();


            client.Disconnect();

            label1.Text = "Status: Restart completed";
        }
    }
```

This is my code. Normally, if you type a command (like LS) it will return the output, then let your type again. But in this case, the server keeps running so it will not let you type anything again, thus its not recognized as the command has finished, as it is still running.

Comment: You should state the exception [that you are not catching].

Comment: yeah thats the weird part, no exception :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I get you right, but I would wrap `try` and `catch` around the problematic code, especially if you don't care about the output in that case.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new SshClient("IP", "USER", "PASS"))
    {

        label1.Text = "Status: Initiated restart";
        try
        {
            client.Connect();
            var cmd = client.RunCommand("./server restart && ./server2 restart");
            var result = cmd.Execute();


            client.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        label1.Text = "Status: Restart completed";
    }
}
```

Comment: This didnt work unfortunately, still just remains crashed forever. The command is executed, thats for sure. In the console i get this: http://marumbo.com/screenshots/devenv_9Oj1yfuSy6.png perhaps this helps in some way

Comment: `Code 0x0` shouldn't crash the application. Is the code running into the exception? If so, what exception do you get? Or what line in the code exactly causes the app to crash?

Comment: It does not run in to the exception for some reason.So nothing is output by the catch statement :/

Comment: Sorry @josibu, i read the sentence wrong. It does not run in to the exception at all, so im not sure where it is crashing currently.